Understanding the conditioning on random variables
I was doing a proof (Markov property for a Poisson process) and i get block on a step.
Let's put some context : We consider a continuous stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ at values in a discrete space ($\mathbb{N}$) that has holding time $(S_n)_{n \geq 1}$ that are independent and that all follow an exponential distribution of rate $\lambda$. We have also $J_n$ defined as $J_0 = 0$ and $J_n = S_0 + S_1 + \ldots + S_n$ verifying $X_{J_n} = n$ for all $n$. We call that a poisson process.
We want to prove the following property :
$\textbf{Theorem} :$
Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Then, for any $s \geq 0$, $(X_{s+t} - X_{s})_{t \geq 0}$ is also a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, independent of $(X_r : r \leq s)$
For some $i$, we condition on $\{X_s = i\}$
We define $\tilde{S}_1 = S_{i+1} - (s-J_1)$, $\tilde{S}_n = S_{i+n}$ for $n \geq 2$ (the holding times of the new process). We already know that all these random variables are mutually independent because $(S_n)$ are. We also know that $\tilde{S_n}$ follows an exponential distribution of rate $\lambda$ for all $n \geq 2$.
But we want to prove two things (still under $X_s = i$) :

$\tilde{S_1}$ follows an exponential distribution of rate $\lambda$
$(\tilde{S_n})_{n \geq 1}$ are independant of $(S_1, \ldots, S_s)$

In the proof, they don't put any mathematical details just sentences which makes it a bit confusing for me.
Passing from $\mathbb{P}(\tilde{S_1} \geq t | X_s = i) = \mathbb{P}(S_{i+1} \geq t + (s-J_i) | S_{i+1} > s - J_i, J_i \leq s)$ to : $\mathbb{P}(S_{i+1} \geq t)$ would be fine. If I consider $J_i$ as known (hence as a constant) i can use the memoryless property of exponential distributions and independence and I can conclude. But, $J_i$ is a random variable that is also continuous so I can't use that strategy or conditioning on fixed value.
So what the book suggest is that we use conditioning with respect to random variables $S_1, \ldots, S_n$. I have this definition, if $A$ is an event $\mathbb{P}(A | S_1, \ldots, S_n) = \mathbb{E}[1_A | \sigma(S_1, \ldots, S_n) ]$.
I understand the idea behind : if I know all the information concerning $S_1, \ldots, S_n$, $J_i$ is also known and I will be able to apply my memoryless property. The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the concept...
Should I write : $\mathbb{P}(S_{i+1} \geq t + (s - J_i) | S_1, \ldots, S_n | S_{i+1} > s - J_i, J_i \leq s)$ ? Because I need, in order to condition an event to a sigma-algebra, to fix a probability space and I should take the one with the probability measure resulting from the conditioning : $S_{i+1} > s - J_i, J_i \leq s$.
And then, how I manage to step by step conclude cause I don't know how to manipulate $\mathbb{P}(A | \mathcal{F})$ at all. I have never seen rigorous example of that. So can anyone who know well the subject help me to better understand that proof.
PS : I am referring to the proof of the Norris book Markov Chains, theorem 2.4.1 (available online if I have not been clear)
